# Selenium IDE able to find element using Find button but uable to click

Tags: selenium-ide

I am new to Selenium, my recorded script generated the code `//td[@id='_t6q2md']/div/div` for a button. When I use the find button it highlights the button, but when I run the script it doesn't fail but neither does it click on the button.

the log shows:

```
[info] Executing: |clickAt |//td[@id='_t6q2md']/div/div | |
```

I have tried various xpath's but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you tried adding a pause before the command? Have you tried exporting this to a language, such as C# or Java, and seeing if it actually executes OK when using SeleniumRC or WebDriver?

Answer (score 0):

I'm far away from being Selenium expert, but have some experience with Selenese, with tests written in plain html. I did not use Selenium IDE, except for command reference, but with Selenium 1 html test-suits it is a common issue when something does not work properly like this. As for me I used to find workarounds like using different command or "runScript" command if nothing else helped. E.g. you can try "mouseUp" or "mouseDown" commands instead of "click". Or you can try smth like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>runScript</td>
    <td>
        var ev = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        ev.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, true, false, 0, null);
        document.querySelector('#_t6q2md div div').dispatchEvent(ev);
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```